# Pass commandline args into another script

Tags: bash, shell, getopts

I have couple of scripts which call into each other. However when I pass

Snippet from buid-and-run-node.sh

```
OPTIND=1 # Reset getopts in case it was changed in a previous run
while getopts "hn:c:f:s:" opt; do
    case "$opt" in
        h)
            usage
            exit 1
            ;;
        n)
            container_name=$OPTARG
            ;;
        c)
            test_command=$OPTARG
            ;;
        s)
            src=$OPTARG
            ;;
        *)
            usage
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
done

$DIR/build-and-run.sh -n $container_name -c $test_command -s $src -f $DIR/../dockerfiles/dockerfile_node
```

Snippet from build-and-run.sh

```
OPTIND=1 # Reset getopts in case it was changed in a previous run
while getopts "hn:c:f:s:" opt; do
    case "$opt" in
        h)
            usage
            exit 1
            ;;
        n)
            container_name=$OPTARG
            ;;
        c)
            test_command=$OPTARG
            ;;
        f)
            dockerfile=$OPTARG
            ;;
        s)
            src=$OPTARG
            ;;
        *)
            usage
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
done
```

I am calling it as such

```
build-and-run-node.sh -n test-page-helper -s ./ -c 'scripts/npm-publish.sh -r test/test-helpers.git -b patch'
```

with the intention that npm-publish.sh should run with the -r and -b parameters. However when I run the script I get

```
build-and-run.sh: illegal option -- r
```

which obviously means it is the build-and-run command that is consuming the -r. How do I avoid this?

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ would catch this for you automatically, without need for human review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need double quotes around `$test_command` in buid-and-run-node.sh, otherwise that variable is being split on the white space and appears to contain arguments for buid-and-run.sh.  Like this:

```
$DIR/build-and-run.sh -n $container_name -c "$test_command" -s $src -f $DIR/../dockerfiles/dockerfile_node
```

#### Further Info

As the comment below rightly points out, it's good practice to quote *all* variables in Bash, unless you know you want them off (for example, to enable shell globbing).  It's also helpful, at least in cases where the variable name is part of a larger word, to use curly braces to delineate the variable name.  This is to prevent later characters from being treated as part of the variable name [if they're legal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28114999/what-are-the-rules-for-valid-identifiers-e-g-functions-vars-etc-in-bash).  So a better command call might look like:

```
"${DIR}/build-and-run.sh" -n "$container_name" -c "$test_command" -s "$src" -f "${DIR}/../dockerfiles/dockerfile_node"
```

Comment: Might as well add quotes everywhere else they're missing while you're at it, no? Better to encourage folks to enable string-splitting and globbing (by leaving off quotes) only for expansions where they explicitly *want* these behaviors, than to have them on-by-default and then off-by-necessity; in the latter case, the correctness of one's scripts correlates much too closely with the breadth of one's test cases exercised in determining where necessity exists.