# How to define completion for function name "pattern"?

Tags: bash, bash-completion

I have several functions working only with directories, all function names following this pattern (ending in **_dir**):

```
something_dir () { ... }
something_else_dir() { ... }
...
```

And for all of those, I define completion with:

```
complete -A directory something_dir something_else_dir ...
```

---

Is it possible to define completion for all functions automatically so that every new function ending in **_dir** would complete just directories?

Comment: One idea I had was to define a function (to be applied with `complete -F myfunc`) that would look at its first argument to determine if ends with `_dir`. However, I'm not sure how to make sure that function is applied to *all* commands (and not just commands without predefined completions), and how to return the expected completions if the command name does *not* end with `_dir`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `compgen -A function` to list all functions; then `grep -E '.*_dir$'` to filter out functions ending with `_dir`.

```
complete -A directory $(compgen -A function | grep -E '.*dir$')
```

This assumes that all function names ending with `_dir` are free of special symbols like `*` and spaces. According to the [specification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28115066/6770384), this should always be the case.

This command will only set up completion for already existing functions. To automatically add completion for functions you will define in an interactive session, add the command to `PROMPT_COMMAND` so that it will be executed at every prompt.

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="complete -A directory \$(compgen -A function | grep -E '.*dir$')"
```

Comment: That's a nice idea. Although, it won't automatically work for new functions I add after. But I guess that's not even possible.

Comment: @mickp It is possible with `PROMPT_COMMAND`. I edited my answer.