# Bash script - user input 'not an identifier:'

Tags: bash

I am new to bash scripting but I am trying to write a script that creates a react app amongst other things. In the script I would like to pass a variable in the the `npx create-react-app ..` command. When I run my script I get an error saying 'ReactAppInitialisation.sh:12: not an identifier: app-name'. Where am I going wrong? many thanks!

```
printf "${green}What would you like to call your new react app?\n"

read app-name

npx create-react-app "${app-name}"
```

Comment: Related: [What are the rules for valid identifiers (e.g. functions, vars, etc) in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28114999/673852)

Comment: The wording from `man bash` is: `word` - A sequence of characters considered as a single unit by the shell. Also known as a `token`. `name` - A word consisting only of *alphanumeric characters and underscores*, and beginning with an alphabetic character or an underscore. Also referred to as an `identifier`. `PARAMETERS` A `parameter` is an entity that stores values. ... A `variable` is a parameter denoted by a `name`. ... A `variable` may be assigned to by a statement of the form `name=[value]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `-` in variable names. Only letters, digits, and `_` are allowed.

Try:

```
read -r app_name
npx create-react-app "${app_name}"
```